# Can I create a new agent in Jenkins pipeline even after the job started?

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

Is it possible for a pipeline to do something like below?

1. Clone the source code.
2. Get the agent container image from the source code as a different version of the source code has a different version image.
3. Use that image to create a new agent.
4. Build code inside of the newly created agent.

pipeline {

```
agent {
    kubernetes {
        label "k8s-xxx-${cto.devops.jenkins.Utils.getTimestamp()}"
        inheritFrom "k8s-dind-rootless"
        defaultContainer "xxx"
        yaml cciContainers([
            [
                name: "agent_1",
                image: "image_1",
                alwaysPullImage: false,
                ttyEnabled: true,
                args: ""
            ]
        ])
    }
}

stages {
    stage('I') {
        steps {
            script {
                
                // Checkout specific version of the source code.
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: "${USER_GIVEN_SHA}"]],
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                    extensions: [
                        [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: "myrepo"],
                        [
                            $class: 'CloneOption', depth: 1, noTags: false,
                            honorRefspec: true, reference: '', shallow: true, timeout: 40
                        ]
                    ],
                    submoduleCfg: [],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                        credentialsId: 'xxx',
                        url: 'xxxx'
                    ]]
                ])
                
                // Get the specific version of the image for a specific env setup.
                def image_2 = """${sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cd myrepo && grep image= a_file | cut -d= -f2")}""".trim()
                
                // Use the parsed image url to create an agent.
                agent {
                    kubernetes {
                        label "k8s-xxx-${cto.devops.jenkins.Utils.getTimestamp()}"
                        inheritFrom "k8s-dind-rootless"
                        defaultContainer "xxx"
                        yaml cciContainers([
                            [
                                name: "agent_2",
                                image: "image_2",
                                alwaysPullImage: false,
                                ttyEnabled: true,
                                args: ""
                            ]
                        ])
                    }
                }
                
                // Build source code inside of agent_2.
                agent("agent_2") {
                    sh '''
                        make
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

As no answers for many days, I asked chatGPT and got below answers:

No, it is not possible to create a new agent in a Jenkins pipeline after the job has started. The agent is defined at the beginning of the pipeline, and it specifies where the pipeline will be executed.

When a Jenkins pipeline starts running, it locks the resources it needs, including the agent where it is running. Once the pipeline is running, it cannot dynamically create or switch to a different agent during its execution.

If you need to run a stage or a portion of the pipeline on a different agent, you can define multiple stages with different agents at the beginning of the pipeline. Each stage will be executed on the specified agent as defined at the start of the pipeline.

Alternatively, you can use the node step to dynamically allocate a node or agent for a specific stage or block within the pipeline. However, this allocation must be done before the pipeline starts running, as it defines the agent for that particular stage.

To summarize, the agent in a Jenkins pipeline is defined at the beginning, and you cannot create a new agent or switch to a different agent during the execution of the pipeline.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: I understand that it's odd that you can't post an answer to your own question when it from ChatGPT, but that really is the policy at the moment.  We just have *way* too many people using ChatGPT irresponsibly here, so for now, all usage is banned.  I do [hope this changes in the future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389675/902710), but for now, I do recommend you delete the answer.  You can undelete it if and when the policy changes.